# Combining attributes of different arff files

Tags: java, merge, weka, arff

I am working on a project with Weka and I have two different **arff** files as follows:

**file1**:

```
@attribute class {yes, no}    
@attribute a numeric    
@data    
{0 yes, 1 2}    
{0 yes}
```

**file2**:

```
@attribute class {yes, no}    
@attribute b numeric    
@attribute a numeric    
@data    
{0 yes, 1 2}    
{0 no, 1 1, 2 1}
```

Is there a way to create a new file by combining these two arff files as follows?

***file3:***

```
@attriute class{yes, no}    
@attribute a numeric    
@attribute b numeric    
@data
{0 yes, 1 2} ("copied" from file 1)    
{0 yes} ("copied" from file 1)    
{0 yes, **2** 2} ("copied" from file 2)    
{0 no, **2** 1, **1** 1} ("copied" from file 2)
```

Merging and does not work, since I have different attributes on every file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [class](http://bioweka.sourceforge.net/docs/api/bioweka/filters/universal/MergeSets.html) offers the API to combine different datasets. The only requeriment is that the .arff files must have different relation names.